# Switching use of page objects in test - Geb Groovy Spock

Tags: user-interface, groovy, spock, functional-testing, geb

I'm writing UI functional tests with Spock, Groovy and Geb implementing the page object pattern. During my flow of events im navigating away from the current page to get a result and as a result, i need to switch the page object in my test but havent been able to do so successfully

Test case below:

```
    def "Navigate to Second Page"() {
    when: "I navigate to second page"

    redirctButton.click()

    then: "Second Page Url should show"
    browser.getCurrentUrl() == secondpageUrl
}

def "Use method form second page"() {
    when: "Im on second page"
    SecondPage.performSearch("search")

    then: "result should show"
    SecondPage.resultBox == ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [at-checking](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-checking) for your page objects, then you can use the `at` method to verify that you are on the expected page, making `browser.getCurrentUrl() == secondpageUrl` obsolete. The other effect of the `at`-check is that it changes the current page and also returns the page object for strongly typed access. If you don't care about strongly typed access you can remove the `expect` block in the second test, it is only there to give you access to typed page object.

```
@Stepwise
class PageTest extends GebReportingSpec {

def "Navigate to Second Page"() {
    when: "I navigate to second page"
    redirctButton.click()

    then: "Second Page Url should show"
    at SecondPage
}

def "Use method form second page"() {
    expect:
    def secondPage = at SecondPage

    when: "Im on second page"
    secondPage.performSearch("search")

    then: "result should show"
    secondPage.resultBox == ""
}
}
```